# 'Vektor2' could not be found

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am beginner and I do know how fix this:
 The type or namespace name 'Vektor2' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Where is that type defined?  Have you tried including that namespace in the `using` directives at the top of the file, as the error suggests?

Comment: You should be using `Vector2`, not `Vektor2`. This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Comment: You are missing a ```DLL```

Comment: The correct class is `Vector2`.

Comment: Your title is bad. "I NEED HALP" isn't a question nor does it summarize the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to use Vector2? with c not k, isn't it?

Documentation here: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.html

Good Luck and welcome!